# How do I check Laptop Battery Status in a .NET 7 ConsoleApp?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to check the battery status in a .NET 7 ConsoleApp. How can I do this in a nice and clean way?

What I tried:

- I've checked the Microsoft Docs which refers to Windows.Forms which is not supported in .NET 7 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.powerstatus?view=windowsdesktop-7.0.
- Another way to do it is using the Windows System Information and extracting it, however there might be better/ built-in options in Windows.

Comment: A Microsoft person built an app called Vista Battery Saver or something like that and it was open source, I assume the code is around somewhere...

Comment: [This CodeGuru article](https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/manipulating-system-power-settings-through-net/) has some suggestions. I'd try their WMI method first

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 6+ (which of course includes .NET 7), I wrote a wrapper around the win32 [System Power Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-power-status) APIs. My code not only wraps `GetSystemPowerStatus` in a convenient way (which gives a snapshot of battery and power status), but also lets you subscribe to OS events to be notified when:

- **The power source changes**
- **Battery percentage changes**
- **Battery saver turns on/off**
- Current monitor's display state changes
- The lid opens/closes
- **The power scheme changes**
- The primary monitor turns on/off
- The session display's state changes
- The system enters/leaves "away mode"
- The system is not idle
- The user is/isn't active

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerStatus